# c# compare 2 strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to do something in C# but just not sure of the syntax.

I return a `string` from a database and want to check if that `string` is present anywhere in a `TextBox`.

How do I do this?

Comment: textBox1.Text.Contains("needle")

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the string is contained within one particular textbox, or you want to check if the string is in any textbox on a particular form?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: you have a typo, there - I think you meant `tbHaystack.Text.Contains("needle")`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Commit yourself. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question.

You can use the Contains method to test if your string is contained within the textbox value

```
TextBox1.Text.Contains(yourString)
```

Comment: If you want the search to be case insensitive then you may want to specify a string comparison mode. e.g.: TextBox1.Text.Contains(yourString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: thats the very thing - thanks both of you.  To be honest yeah it is kinda obvious, I was over complicating things.  ta

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is too obvious?:

```
if ( myTextBox.Text.Contains(myStringFromDB) )
{
    // Is contained, do something...
}
else
{
    // Is not contained, do something else...
}
```

For Windows Forms, see [this `TextBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx), for Web Forms see [this `TextBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx).